# DBMS stored procedure- get values from existing table

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a table `Age_cal`, Vaccine Information and `Medical_information` table as follows:

[image: Age_cal]

[image: VaccineInformation]

[image: Medical Information Table]

I am trying to write a stored procedure where, I will be able to insert the values into a table named vaccine based on the `vaccine_information` table.

In med_info table we have DOB, and the age is calculated and stored in `age_cal` table along with the age grp and `medicalID` (PK). The vaccine information table has name of vaccine and to which age group it needs to be given to.

So while inserting a value into Vaccine table, I want to give the values `medicalId`, date it was given on , dose no and facility name as parameters. But I want the vaccine name to be automatically selected based on the age group they belong to.

I have written the following stored procedure, but null value is getting inserted into the vaccine_name. Please help me with inserting the vaccine name using the stored procedure.

[image]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[allot_v]
    @MedicalID int,
    @VaccineDate date,
    @DoseNo int,
    @facilityName varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @injectvaccine varchar(20)

    SET @injectvaccine = (SELECT dbo.VaccineInformation.VaccineName 
                          FROM dbo.VaccineInformation, dbo.Age_Cal 
                          WHERE dbo.Age_Cal.grp = dbo.VaccineInformation.grp 
                            AND dbo.Age_Cal.MedicalID = @MedicalID)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vaccination]
        ([MedicalID], [VaccineName], [VaccineDate], [DoseNo], [FacilityName])
     VALUES (@MedicalID, @injectvaccine, @VaccineDate, @DoseNo, @facilityName)
END
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Sure, Thankyou for the input. I will try to avoid it.

Comment: As explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data. No one can copy/paste data from a picture. Sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure worked with the following code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[allot_v]
    @MedicalID int,
    @VaccineDate date,
    @DoseNo int,
    @facilityName varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @injectvaccine varchar(20)

    SET @injectvaccine = (SELECT dbo.VaccineInformation.VaccineName 
                          FROM dbo.VaccineInformation, dbo.Age_Cal 
                          WHERE dbo.Age_Cal.grp = dbo.VaccineInformation.grp 
                            AND dbo.Age_Cal.MedicalID = @MedicalID)

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vaccination]
        ([MedicalID], [VaccineName], [VaccineDate], [DoseNo], [FacilityName])
     VALUES (@MedicalID, @injectvaccine, @VaccineDate, @DoseNo, @facilityName)
END
```

Comment: You're still using that deprecated, out-of-style and non-standard "join" syntax by having comma-separated list of tables after your `FROM`  .....